# showing images in UIScrollview horizontally on ipad and getting tag of image on tap

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I am showing images in UIScrollView with UIImageView.I added UIGestureRecognizer to each ImageView and also I am setting tag property of Image View.I want tag of Image view on Tap on particular Image View.But I am only getting Tag of last ImageView.Pasting Code below.Your help will be appreciated.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewDidTapped:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 60, self.view.bounds.size.width-20, self.view.bounds.size.height-100)];

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.indicatorStyle = UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleWhite;
[scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:YES];
[scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

float width;
for (NSDictionary *dict in object) {
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(width, 0,      self.view.bounds.size.width-20, self.view.bounds.size.height-40)];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSDate *date = [dateformatter  dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"id"]]];
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
backgroundImageView.tag = timeStamp;
[backgroundImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[dict objectForKey:@"coverImage"]]];
AFImageRequestOperation *operation = [AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:request
imageProcessingBlock:nil
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image){
 backgroundImageView.image = image;
}
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
}];
[operation start];
width = width + backgroundImageView.frame.size.width;

[backgroundImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[imageViewArray addObject:backgroundImageView];
[scrollView addSubview:backgroundImageView];
}
```

And added method for getting gesture event

```
- (void)imageViewDidTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture;

UIImageView *tappedImageView = (UIImageView *)[tapGesture view];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateformatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSLog(@"Issue Date :%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:tappedImageView.tag]]);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have many imageView but only one UITapGestureRecognizer. you should add a gesture recognizer for each imageView.

Comment: as you see i have added gesture recognizer on every image view..and doing new gesture recognizer for each new image view will be not so logical

Comment: one more thing, NSTimeInterval is double type and view's tag can not be used to store it.

Comment: code i have written is working fine but i'm just getting tap gesture event for last imageView only which is not expected.

Comment: just add a new tap gesture for each image view, each tap gesture only have one view to attach.

Answer (score 0):

Create `UITapGestureRecognizer` inside the for loop.

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in object) {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer;
    tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewDidTapped:)];

    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;

    tapRecognizer.delegate = self;

    // your code for image imageview

    [imageview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
}
```