# UITapGestureRecognizer Only Works on Last Item

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm creating a resume app (mostly for fun) and can't seem to get the tap gesture recognizer to work for me. What I'd like is to have a single label display the information and have it change depending on which title label they tap below. Here is the code I've written:

```
import UIKit

class WorkHistoryViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var jobOne: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobTwo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobThree: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobFour: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var jobFive: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var workHistoryDescriptionLabel: UILabel!
    let tapRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tapRec.addTarget(self, action: "tappedLabel")
        jobOne.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
        jobTwo.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
        jobThree.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
        jobFour.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
        jobFive.addGestureRecognizer(tapRec)
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func tappedLabel() {
        workHistoryDescriptionLabel.text = "It worked!"
    }
}
```

What's happening is that the last label to have addGestureRecognizer() called in viewDidLoad() is the only one that works. If I comment out the last line then only the label above it works. I also tried to enable user interaction on each of the labels programmatically and on the attributes inspector and neither changed anything.

Comment: you have to add different tapgestures to every label

Comment: You are allocating it only once and how it supposed to be working on every label?

Answer (score 4):

As per Apple's **Event Handling Guidelines**

> **Gesture Recognizers Are Attached to a View**
>
> Every gesture recognizer is
>   associated with **one view**. By contrast, a view can have multiple
>   gesture recognizers, because a single view might respond to many
>   different gestures. For a gesture recognizer to recognize touches that
>   occur in a particular view, you must attach the gesture recognizer to
>   that view. When a user touches that view, the gesture recognizer
>   receives a message that a touch occurred before the view object does.
>   As a result, the gesture recognizer can respond to touches on behalf
>   of the view.

So you need to create multiple instances of `UITapGestureRecognizer` and attach them to each view, even if they perform same actions.

For instance,

```
let tapRecOne = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapRecOne.addTarget(self, action: "tappedLabel")
jobOne.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecOne)

let tapRecTwo = UITapGestureRecognizer()
tapRecTwo.addTarget(self, action: "tappedLabel")
jobTwo.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecTwo)
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create new object of tap gestures to get your work done.You can refer [showing images in UIScrollview horizontally on ipad and getting tag of image on tap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629267/showing-images-in-uiscrollview-horizontally-on-ipad-and-getting-tag-of-image-on)

Answer (score 1):

Here is Apple's documentation as defined [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIGestureRecognizer).

> A gesture recognizer operates on touches hit-tested to a **specific** view and all of that view’s subviews. It thus must be associated with that view. To make that association you must call the UIView method addGestureRecognizer:. A gesture recognizer doesn’t participate in the view’s responder chain.

That means that you need to have separate "UIGestureRecognizer" instances for each view. That should sort out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode has a small icon in Xcode you see in this screen shot that you can click on when your app is running. As I put in this screenshot its invaluable when trying to understand what is happening with UI issues?

[image]